# Internal compiler error: Bus error

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

Im trying to make a UITableView with a View with Details but I get two errors.
After the following code I got two times the same errors:
'Internal compiler error: Bus error'
and I have no idea why? Can someone help me?
You can find a image of the code under [here](http://www.joelschmid.ch/error.jpg).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (self.verwaltungDetailViewController == nil){
    verwaltungDetailViewController *aVerwaltungDetail = [[verwaltungDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VerwaltungDetailView" bundle:nil];
    self.verwaltungDetailViewController = aVerwaltungDetail;
    [aVerwaltungDetail release];

}
verwaltungDetailViewController.title =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [verwaltungsArray objectAtIndex:row]];



NatersAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.VerwaltungNavController pushViewController:verwaltungDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

}

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Which compiler are you using ? gcc 4.0, 4.2, LLVM, other ? And what platform, Mac OS X or iOS ?

Comment: GCC 4.0 and I tried it on iOS Device and Simulator, but it makes no difference... I got also two warnings, you can find them under the following [link](http://www.joelschmid.ch/error1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you've got a *class* somewhere called `VerwaltungDetailViewController` (note the uppercase 'V') and you are mixing it up with an *instance variable & property* called `verwaltungDetailViewController` (note the lowercase 'v').  In the first line of the `if` block, you are attempting to create an instance of the latter, when you should be attempting to create an instance of the former.  Your code should look something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
if (self.verwaltungDetailViewController == nil){
    VerwaltungDetailViewController *aVerwaltungDetail = [[verwaltungDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VerwaltungDetailView" bundle:nil];
    self.verwaltungDetailViewController = aVerwaltungDetail;
    [aVerwaltungDetail release];

}
verwaltungDetailViewController.title =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [verwaltungsArray objectAtIndex:row]];



NatersAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.verwaltungNavController pushViewController:verwaltungDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

**Edit:** You also make the mistake in the last line of code, except in reverse.