# Xcode Bus Error When Compiling

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, bus-error

My iPhone app was compiling just fine, then all of the sudden, it started failing to compile, with the error:

> LLVM GCC 4.2 Error Internal Compiling Error: Bus Error 10

It compiles just fine for the simulator but it won't build to a device. I have tried what seems like everything, and nothing works. There is no stack trace that I can post. Additionally, the code is too long to paste all of it here since I can't be sure exactly where the problem is (again, no stack trace).

How can I narrow this down?

EDIT: I KNOW that I tried this before, but setting the compiler to GCC instead of LLVM GCC successfully compiled the app. I wish I knew the reason why Xcode was behaving this way, but for now all I can chalk this up to is ghosts.

Comment: How about you help yourself and supply enough information to make the question answerable.

Comment: @Nick, you are seriously going to have to provide a lot more information than this.  Some context and source would be great.  Stack trace if possible.  I suspect this question will be closed quickly otherwise and then you won't get an answer

Comment: Sorry everyone, Im just panicking. My project was compiling fine, and I tried to build it to my phone (the same build, no changes were made), but then it started with the error. It doesn't SAY anything... just "LLVM GCC 4.2 Error Internal Compiling Error: Bus Error 10 at the bottom of a .m file on the @end line The source is far too long to post--unless there is some specific place you would need to see?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493647/xcode-4-internal-compiler-error-bus-error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042256/internal-compiler-error-bus-error

Comment: Thank you, but I already saw these posts. I'm going to go look at what Ive changed recently, I suppose. I've also read online that it may be a memory issue? I have restarted, shut down, etc several times, but nothing worked.

Comment: I know EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors don't usually occur in the exact line of code that caused them. Are bus errors similar? As in, should I start looking around the @end line that the error is marked on?

Comment: I made some edits based on your comments

Comment: thank you. I have been searching for over half an hour, and doing anything i can think of, but still no luck. The other links posted above didn't help :( I really don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've often gotten this error when there's some syntax error and the compiler can't move forward. Older versions of Xcode used to say something like this:

> confused by earlier errors, bailing out

(I suspect it's the same thing internally.)

Go back and cheek your recent changes. I'll bet it's a semicolon or quote missing somewhere. This is why we are supposed to hit compile more than once an hour. I've had this before. It's not a major disaster. You didn't break any of the dev tools. Just review your code and look fr the syntax error.